# Is it possible to save only Year with strotime function?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, strtotime

I use jquery datepicker plugin. 
I record a date without the day and month but the year only, eg: 1994 
I record this information in my database through strtotime (1994)

When I display this information later, it gives me 30 November 1993. 
I don't understand. Is it possible to record only year with strotime function. And the thing I'm doing is it possible?

Thank you and good day

Comment: Are you using ``PHP's strtotime`` function? could you please add PHP code as well.

Comment: strtotime("0-0-1994");

Comment: You can't store a date with zero for the day or month. You'll always need to use a complete valid date and then just format it to display/use just the year. Alternatively don't use dates at all and just store the year as an integer. If this doesn't help you'll need to show us **all** the **relevant** code by editing the question.